# How to spinner adapter calling to main screen?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-spinner

I have two class. They are "Start" and "MySpinner". I want to add a spinner using class of the MySpinner in Start screen but arrayadapter has an error in the MySpinner. My app don't open.

Start Class:

```
public class Start extends ActionBarActivity {

RelativeLayout MainRelLay;
ScrollView MainScrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MainScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    this.setContentView(MainScrollView);

    MainRelLay = new RelativeLayout(this);

    MainScrollView.addView(MainRelLay);

    MySpinner spinner = new MySpinner();
    MainRelLay.addView(spinner.addSpinner(this));

}
```

MySpinner Class:

```
public class MySpinner {

Spinner sp;
String ArSp[];
ArrayAdapter AA;

public Spinner addSpinner(Context cnt) {

    sp = new Spinner(cnt);

    ArSp[0] = "A";
    ArSp[1] = "B";

    sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(cnt, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ArSp));

    return sp;

}
```

Comment: You never initialize `ArSp`. You say `ArSp[0] = "A";` but at that point `ArSp[0]` doesn't exist. Also, if you get errors, at least tell us what they are and/or post your logcat output.

Comment: Where are your XML layouts?

Comment: The issue is solved. I don't use xml. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few compile issues in your class. My first suggestion for you would be to use an IDE that will highlight when you have compile errors.

The issue you are running into is you have not initialized your array. You need to initialize like

```
String[] arSp = new String[2];
```

This will give you a String array of size 2.

Also, it is best practice to start your variables with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks Brittany, I agree with you :)